Association named 'versions' was not found on ActiveStorage::Blob; perhaps you misspelled it?
In a Ruby on Rails 7.0.8.5 app where we've been writing to a single bucket for years, I have the need to write to a different bucket for one model...
I am trying to write attachments to an S3 bucket from the local development environment.  I added the service name to the has_one_attached in my model
  has_one_attached :file, service: :amazon_backups

I added this entry to storage.yml
amazon_backups:
  service: S3
    access_key_id: <%= ENV.fetch('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID') %>
    secret_access_key: <%= ENV.fetch('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY') %>
    region: <%= ENV.fetch('AWS_REGION') { 'us-east-1' } %>
    bucket: <%= ENV.fetch('AWS_BACKUPS_BUCKET') %>

After restarting the web server, whenever I save the record (which would also upload the file). I get

Association named 'versions' was not found on ActiveStorage::Blob;
perhaps you misspelled it

I even tried setting this bucket in development.rb to troubleshoot
config.active_storage.service = :amazon_backups
It's as though ActiveStorage is trying to create versions of the file?  Wild guess.
Anyone else see this?  I googled but came up with nothing.
Here is the stack trace.  It looks like the paper_trail gem is being called and there is a method named versions.
app/models/db_backup.rb:26:in `upload_db': Association named 'versions' was not found on ActiveStorage::Blob; perhaps you misspelled it? (ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError)
    from app/models/db_backup.rb:18:in `create_and_upload'
    from (irb):2:in `<main>'
/Users/dsadaka/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4@mdu7/gems/activerecord-7.0.8.5/lib/active_record/associations.rb:302:in `association': Association named 'versions' was not found on ActiveStorage::Blob; perhaps you misspelled it? (ActiveRecord::AssociationNotFoundError)
    from /Users/dsadaka/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4@mdu7/gems/activerecord-7.0.8.5/lib/active_record/associations/builder/association.rb:104:in `versions'
    from /Users/dsadaka/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4@mdu7/gems/paper_trail-13.0.0/lib/paper_trail/record_trail.rb:297:in `public_send'
    from /Users/dsadaka/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4@mdu7/gems/paper_trail-13.0.0/lib/paper_trail/record_trail.rb:297:in `versions'
    from /Users/dsadaka/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4@mdu7/gems/paper_trail-13.0.0/lib/paper_trail/record_trail.rb:74:in `block in record_create'
    from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
    from /Users/dsadaka/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4@mdu7/gems/paper_trail-13.0.0/lib/paper_trail/record_trail.rb:69:in `record_create'
    from /Users/dsadaka/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4@mdu7/gems/paper_trail-13.0.0/lib/paper_trail/model_config.rb:41:in `block in on_create'
    from /Users/dsadaka/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4@mdu7/gems/activesupport-7.0.8.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:467:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/dsadaka/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4@mdu7/gems/activesupport-7.0.8.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:467:in `block in make_lambda'
    from /Users/dsadaka/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4@mdu7/gems/activesupport-7.0.8.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:236:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
    from /Users/dsadaka/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4@mdu7/gems/activesupport-7.0.8.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:599:in `block in invoke_after'
    from /Users/dsadaka/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4@mdu7/gems/activesupport-7.0.8.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:599:in `each'
    from /Users/dsadaka/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4@mdu7/gems/activesupport-7.0.8.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:599:in `invoke_after'
    from /Users/dsadaka/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4@mdu7/gems/activesupport-7.0.8.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:108:in `run_callbacks'
    from /Users/dsadaka/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4@mdu7/gems/activesupport-7.0.8.5/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:929:in `_run_create_callbacks'
    from /Users/dsadaka/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.4@mdu7/gems/activerecord-7.0.8.5/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:459:in `_create_record'
    ... 116 levels...


please add the stacktrace to your question. - Do you have versioning enabled in the s3 bucket?

Stack trace added

It is strange that paper_trail is trying to hook into ActiveStorage::Blob are you sure you haven't done anything odd in a configuration?

It's definitely paper_trail.  I commented out the code in the active_storage.rb initializer
# Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
#   ActiveStorage::Record.has_paper_trail
# end

And now it works fine.  Now I have to figure out how to exclude this model

FIXED!
I Added
PaperTrail.request.disable_model(ActiveStorage::Blob)
to the models initialize method.
